# Tensorflow can't save model

Tags: tensorflow

I encountered this weird problem...I use this code to construct tensorflow saver:

```
tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), max_to_keep=FLAGS.keep)
```

which is supposed to be very standard. However, when I point the saving directory to my custom directory (under my username) instead of "/tmp", all of a sudden, the saved models are files like

**translate.ckpt-329.data-00000-of-00001**

**translate.ckpt-329.index**

**translate.ckpt-329.meta**

I can't find the file "translate.ckpt-329".

The generated checkpoint file is pointing to:

```
model_checkpoint_path: "/Users/.../train_dir/translate.ckpt-329"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "/Users/.../train_dir/translate.ckpt-329"
```

while this file does not exist and create problems for me restoring my model.

Can someone shed any light on this?? What could possibly be the problem?

---

Thanks for the first answer! I guess my bigger problem is the `restore` method:

The original code uses this way to restore a session:

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.train_dir)
model.saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

Which failed with V2 saving :(

```
if ckpt and tf.gfile.Exists(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path):
        logging.info("Reading model parameters from %s" % ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        model.saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    else:
        logging.info("Created model with fresh parameters.")
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Comment: What error did the `restore()` fail with?

Comment: @mrry ahhh! Now I understand...it's the `tf.gfile.Exists()` that failed...not `restore()` failed. Is there a recommended way for me to check if the model has a saved checkpoint file now with V2?

Comment: That's a good question... I don't think there's anything (although you might be able to convince [`tf.train.latest_checkpoint()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#latest_checkpoint) to do the right thing for you. This seems like a reasonable feature request though, because I think quite a few people are running into similar problems... feel free to open a GitHub issue about it, and we'll route it to the right person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** In the new checkpoint format, the "filename" that you pass to the saver is actually used as the prefix of several filenames, and no file with that exact name is written. You can use the old checkpoint format by constructing your [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#Saver.__init__) with the optional argument `write_version=tf.train.SaverDef.V1`.

From the names of the saved files, it appears that you are using the "V2" checkpoint format, which became the default in TensorFlow 0.12. This format stores the checkpoint data in multiple files: one or more data files (e.g. `translate.ckpt-329.data-00000-of-00001` in your case) and an index file (`translate.ckpt-329.index`) that tells TensorFlow where each saved variable is located in the data files. The [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#Saver) uses the "filename" that you pass as the prefix for these files' names, but doesn't produce a file with that exact name.

Although there is no file with the exact name you gave, you can use the value returned from [`saver.save()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#Saver.save) as the argument to a subsequent [`saver.restore()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#Saver.restore), and the other checkpoint locating mechanisms should continue to work as before.

Comment: Is there a way for me to go back to V1?? Mostly because there are some automatic saving/loading mechanism built inside the code (not by me)...and I don't want to disrupt anything.

Comment: Yes: simply pass the optional argument `write_version=tf.train.SaverDef.V1` to the `tf.train.Saver` initializer.

Comment: Thank you!!! This should help! I also updated the question for a bit...if you want to take another look at it